# Why do I get the error that there is garbage at the end of my json when trying to use it with objective c?

Tags: php, json, sqlite

I have a PHP script that takes the data from an sqlite database and then converts it to json using the json_encode() function.  I am getting the data properly but I do not think that it is in the correct format.  Everything works great with one record but when you add another record, I get this error message, Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}

The URL that has the output is www.beklimo.me/sqlitetojson.php

```
if (file_exists($fileName)) {

//echo "The file $fileName exsists";

try{
$dbHandle = new PDO('sqlite:/home3/anyinfc1/public_html/beklimo/checkedintrainsDB.sql');

$dbHandle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$result = $dbHandle->query('SELECT *FROM trainscheckedin');


foreach ($dbHandle->query('SELECT * FROM trainscheckedin') as $row) {
    echo json_encode($row);
}

}catch (PDOException $e){
echo 'EXCEPTION: '.$e->getMessage();
}
}else{

echo "The file $fileName does not exist";

}


?>
```

Any help would be great!  I am beating my head off the wall. I am new to this so I may not have the output in the correct format.  I know that the format works with one entry, just not more then one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are echoing separate JSON objects each time and the receiving end is probably expecting one.  Try to create one that contains all of the rows and echo it:

```
foreach ($dbHandle->query('SELECT * FROM trainscheckedin', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;  // create an array of rows
}

echo json_encode($data);
//  or possibly an object
echo json_encode((object)$data);
```

Comment: That worked out well, now on to my next issue!  Thank you for the help!

Comment: You wouldnt happen to know why the values are repeating like that do you? such as {"postalcode":"48164","0":"48164","latitude":"42.097673","1":"42.097673","longitude":"-83.392775","2":"-83.392775","timestamp":"2015-12-07 10:26:26 0000","3":"2015-12-07 10:26:26 0000"}

Comment: it puts each data under the correct key and then the numeric key

Comment: Like this I mean, {"postalcode":"48164","0":"48164", same data represented with postalcode and "0"

Comment: Several ways: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php I added `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` above.

Comment: Thank you!  That did it. Thanks so much for all your help! SO it was basically how the php retrieved the data and added it to the array that caused the numeric keys then correct?

Comment: @Beanno1116 , yes the default fetch mode is: PDO::FETCH_BOTH, which returns an array indexed by both column name and 0-indexed column number.